# WooCommerce Checkout: Add radio button to disable field

Tags: woocommerce, radio-button, field, checkout, disable

I am looking for a way to add a radio button to the checkout in WooCommerce, which, when clicked, will remove the field in the checkout with the ID "billing_company_wi_vat". The field with this ID is set as required. I will be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to disable the billing address completely?

If yes, then here you are

```
function cs_woocommerce_remote_billing_fields( $fields ) {
unset( $fields['billing_phone'] );
unset( $fields['billing_address_1'] );
unset( $fields['billing_address_2'] );
unset( $fields['billing_city'] );
unset( $fields['billing_postcode'] );
unset( $fields['billing_state'] );
unset( $fields['billing_country'] );
unset( $fields['billing_company'] );

$fields['billing_email']['class'] = array( 'form-row-wide' );

return $fields;
```

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'cs_woocommerce_remote_billing_fields' );

Comment: No, I want to add radio button to checkout. When button will be checked, then field with ID billing_company_wi_vat will be hidden and not required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check for custom checkout. At this point I think its the best option to change anything as you want instead to change in a wrong way the functionality of main checkout which may causes many problems in the future.

Friendly, George

Comment: I am tryed in past many plugins for custom checkout and every plugin have some problems and bugs. All my custom things I am solved with CSS or functions.php. This is last thing what I need to solve. Do you have any idea how to do it?